# Best way to allow water to flow inside this mesh?

Tags: animation, normals, fluid-simulation

I am a blender beginner and after watching some tutorials online I figured I'd give modeling and animation a try.

I am trying to make an oil hourglass animation that will move the liquid downwards.[The hourglass is exactly the same as the one shown here](https://youtu.be/PZnawGM3l6w?t=207), I have a physical reference of it.

The only issue is that my liquid doesn't seem to want to pass through 2 holes I made on the container mesh, I suspect it's because of the wrong facing normals right outside of it:

[image]

I managed to get the liquid to flow inside of the top sphere.

[image]

but It won't flow into the rest of the mesh.

[image]

Will I have to create a new mesh? Help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: If needed I can try uploading my .blend, I didn't see an option to attach one, but I can find a hosting site for it.

Comment: here’s how you can upload a .blend file:  https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file

Comment: Thanks, here is the file if anyone's curious:

https://pasteall.org/blend/2c0eff3d8d25472b8ed1e6bca69f8e46

Comment: Please do not ask the same questions over and over again, please edit your original one instead, thanks. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: Sorry, I figured it has been a while and was left unanswered, so I made a new post again for visibility. I'll mark this as solved to redirect discussion on the new post.